# Which (if any) Trilogy site is appropriate for Quartz Composer questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, superuser

It's pretty darned rare that *I* have a question like this, but here we go. I recently started playing with [Apple's Quartz Composer](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/quartzcomposer/) tool. This tool is a "visual programming language" (Lord how I hate that term) for developing graphic effects, animations and other compositions.

Amongst its uses are things like building screen savers (my current desire with the tool), iTunes visualizations, etc.

It's bundled with Apple's development tool suite (XCode), and is considered by Apple to be a development tool. I'd liken it more to Flash -- it's highly visual, with some scripting enabled. (However, it's considerably *more* visual than Flash is -- you can do amazing things in Flash with nothing but code; near as I can tell so far, you can't do a "nothing but code" project with Quartz Composer. They call that the Core Graphics API instead.)

Part of me says Stack Overflow, because it is considered development, has all of the standard programming constructs (variables, logic, etc), and its development environment can be likened to, say, BizTalk's workflow design tools. Part of me, however, says that Stack Overflow is completely inappropriate, because these compositions are *essentially* code-free -- sure, you can use Javascript in them, but that's about the extent of it. (Again, as far as I can tell so far -- I've only been playing with it a few days.)

Part of me says that Super User might be appropriate in light of the reasons I think Stack Overflow might not be. But Super User *really* feels like the wrong community.

It's not web-based, so DocType is completely out of the question. (Not that we support them here at Meta anyway.)

So, wall of text aside, should questions regarding Quartz Composer go to:

1. Stack Overflow
2. Super User
3. Somewhere else entirely

Answer (score 6):

I agree with your concerns completely and I feel the same way on being SO vs SU material.  I would support posting on either, except I think it would get the swift action of community moderation for migration to the other site back and forth as I am sure some would disagree with its placement on either. I think SO would have many more people that could answer the question though.  I am sure there are some people on SU that have the knowledge to answer, I just think SO would have more and could get an answer much quicker.

... and that previous answer to this question that was completely uncalled for has been taken care of.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's so oddly ambiguous that I think I agree each community would migrate it over to the other. I missed the uncalled-for answer. **SO** dying of curiosity now ... :)

Answer (score 5):

Ask on Stackoverflow.

I'd justify it with that programming isn't about the code, it's about using logic to create an application, no matter if it's JavaScript, C# or *visual code*. Additionally, the chances of finding someone with expertise in it are highest on SO.